# How do I find if a point is inside an SVG element of a parsed but not displayed SVG file?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

The problem is how to find if a point `(x,y)` is inside a general graphical SVG element (e.g. `rect`, `ellipse`, `path`) before it is displayed on-screen. That means that any methods getting the position in screen coordinates are not available - only the data given in the SVG file can be used.

The background is that my company needs a system for tagging SVG elements from Adobe Illustrator, and as AI doesn't allow for much SVG output modification, we have decided to base this on creating a separate layer `tags` with text objects containing the tag text. Then, client-side, the files are parsed and the tags added to the corresponding SVG elements before then removing the `tags` group.

Getting basic coordinates of the tags is easy (using ES5 - sorry). For a given `svg` string:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();

var svgDom = parser.parseFromString(svg, "image/svg+xml");
var tagsElement = svgDom.getElementById("tags");

if (tagsElement) {
    var textElementHtmlCollection = tagsElement.getElementsByTagName("text");
    var textElementArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(textElementHtmlCollection);
    var tagDataArray = textElementArray.map(function (el) {
        return {
            text: el.textContent,
            pos: {
                x: el.transform.baseVal[0].matrix.e,
                y: el.transform.baseVal[0].matrix.f
            }
        };
    });
```

Right now, a VERY basic version of the tagging system is working, but every node type has to be handled separately, and I have gone as far as implementing a modified numeric winding number algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) for `path` nodes (the problems arising with 'close call' cases are not a consideration for the use case):

```
function windingNumber (element,x,y) {
    var isInside, p1 = undefined, p2 = undefined, px, py, R, wn, sum=0;
    var totalLength = element.getTotalLength();

    var resolution = 5;
    var threshold = 0.1;

    for (var len = 0; len <= totalLength; len += resolution) {
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = element.getPointAtLength(len);
        if (p1) {
            px = p1.x - x;
            py = p1.y - y;
            R = px*px + py*py;
            sum += (px*(p2.y-p1.y)/R - py*(p2.x-p1.x)/R);
        }
        wn = sum/(2*Math.PI);
        if (Math.abs(wn) > 1-threshold) {
            isInside = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isInside;
}
```

Now, I have decided that there has to be another way, as the system gets immensely complex when taking into account that there may be all kinds of `transform`s applied to the elements.

Is there a more straightforward way to accomplish this? Ideas for different approaches are also welcome.

*UPDATE* My answer is *terrible*, but it is the one I ended up using. The infrastructure surrounding the app and the problem made it really hard to get the "proper" solution (display SVG hidden, use `document.elementsFromPoint()`) working.

Still, the more maths in the code, the more fun.

Comment: Display it with visibility: hidden or off screen somehow and then call document.elementFromPoint

Comment: You can also use some custom XML parser library to make first piece of code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up doing it is to apply the inverse transformation of the elements to the point I try to find.

```
// Instead of taking into account transformations on the element,
// invert the transformations and apply them to the point.
if (element.transform && element.transform.baseVal) {
    // Get the transformation matrix information.
    var transform = element.transform.baseVal.consolidate();
    if (transform) {
        // Calculate the inverse of the transformation matrix.
        var transformMatrix = transform.matrix;
        var inverseTM = transformMatrix.inverse();

        // Calculate the new x and y values as a matrix multiplication of
        // the inverse transformation matrix and the vector (x,y,1).
        //
        //   a c e       x       a*x + c*y + e       newX
        // ( b d f ) * ( y ) = ( b*x + d*y + f ) = ( newY )
        //   0 0 1       1             1              1
        //
        var newX, newY;
        newX = inverseTM.a*x + inverseTM.c*y + inverseTM.e;
        newY = inverseTM.b*x + inverseTM.d*y + inverseTM.f;
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
    }
}
```

I'll update if I encounter any problems, but this seemed to work surprisingly well.

Beware to anyone doing this: The winding number on SVG elements is not simple, and may well break for more complex shapes. Still, as the shapes are quite simple in our use case, this solution will do.

Answer (score 2):

Robert's suggestion should be the easiest approach.

You should just be able to append your test element to an SVG, check if the point is over using [`elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint), then remove the element again.

```
function testPointInElement(elem, x, y) {
  svg.appendChild(elem);
  var hitElem = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
  // If you remove it again before the browser refreshes, it should not ever be visible
  svg.removeChild(elem);
  return hitElem === elem;
}
```

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

// Generates a sample test element
function sampleElement() {
  var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  path.setAttribute("d", "M 200,300 L 300,100 L 350,350 L 200,200 L 400,200 Z");
  path.setAttribute("fill-rule", "evenodd");
  return path;
}

function testPointInElement(elem, x, y) {
  svg.appendChild(elem);
  var hitElem = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
  // If you remove it again before the browser refreshes, it should not ever be visible
  svg.removeChild(elem);
  return hitElem === elem;
}



var testElem = sampleElement();

svg.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  var x = evt.clientX;
  var y = evt.clientY;
  
  // Find out if any element is at x,y
  if (testPointInElement(testElem, x,y)) {
    alert("Hit!");
  }
});
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg" width="400" height="400">
  <!-- ghost path showing where our test path is -->
  <path d="M 200,300 L 300,100 L 350,350 L 200,200 L 400,200 Z" fill-rule="evenodd" opacity="0.1"/>
</svg>
```

---

In SVG2 it's even easier. You can call [`isPointInFill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInFill) on your element.
**[Update:]** [Supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInFill#browser_compatibility) in all modern browsers (so not IE).